# How to pass current opportunity in which I am working into canvas app Gallery

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have developed one canvas app for searching reference Accounts and add them to opportunity. I have connected my canvas app to opportunity form but it is not automatically selecting the current opportunity rather showing all my opportunity in the app.

How should I pass current opportunity to my app in which I am currently working so that opportunity is automatically selected and then I can move to some other "My Opportunity" if I like. Now, it is selecting the first opportunity by default in the gallery

I have read it could be done using parameters but not sure how to proceed with this. TIA

Comment: Hi All, This something urgent. It would be really helpful if someone could comment here.